# Trouble understanding break

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Could someone please take the time and try to explain how does this code work, don't understand the break part and how the answer at the end is 0.

```
int a=3, x;
switch(a==5){
   case 0: x=0;break;
   case 1: x=1;break;
   case 3: x=3;break;
   case 5: x=5;break;
   default: x=7;
}
printf("%d",x);
```

Comment: First, notice you have `switch(a==5)` and not `switch(a)`.

Comment: `a==5` is false, which in C++ is `0`, so `case 0:` takes affect. The `break;` is to prevent the switch statement from _falling through_ into the next `case`

Comment: `switch(a==5)` is not good code to learn from unless prefixed with something like, "Find the logic error in this code."

Comment: If you don't break, then the execution continues into the statements of the next break. This was done to optitmize cases when for example one case needs additional initialization, but then does the same thing as the following one.

Comment: @ChrisMM Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 3):

Without `break`, execution would continue from each case to the next (fallthrough) and every path would eventually end up at `default` and assign `7` to `x`.

Also note that you have a bug: `switch(a==5)` should be `switch(a)`.

Answer (score 2):

`a==5` returns a true or false value (0 or 1). In this example, most of the cases will not be triggered. Change `switch(a==5)` to `switch(a)`
This means that in your example, case 0 is triggered, because `a==5` results in false (0).

Answer (score 2):

Since `a==5` is false, because `a` is 3, it returns 0.
That's why `case 0:` is being triggered.

`break;` causes the code to stop, and without it the code would continue until `default:`.